# Java Play Framework UnexpectedException applying PropertiesEnhancer

Tags: java, string, exception, playframework

I get the following error on compile:

An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException:
While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer on controllers.xxxxx

I've narrowed it down to the following line in my controller:

String sender_alert_string = "Your message to " + app_user.fullname + " has failed";

With the line, I get the error, without the line, I don't.

I even tried splitting it up into separate strings and then combining them.  Also tried .concat()

Why would an attempt to join strings (as I do in many other places) cause this?

EDIT: I'm beginning to think it has something to do with the @Entity tag just before declarations in my model files.  Alternatives?

EDIT: app_user is of a basic model type User.  constructor below

public User(String app_user_uuid, String fullname, String auth_token)
    {

```
    //timestamp
    Calendar now_time = Application.get_now();
    this.time_modified = now_time;
    this.time_created = now_time;

    //other
    this.app_user_uuid = app_user_uuid;
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.auth_token = auth_token;
    this.timezone_offset = Application.default_timezone_offset;
}
```

Comment: Maybe app_user.fullname is enhanced in some way by Play and there is a problem around this... what's class app_user, a model or something else?

Comment: Yes, app_user is a model and .fullname is a string.  nothing fancy there.  More recently, I also found that a line where I simply try to save a model instance (different model than app_user) causes this same exception.  this makes me thing that theres something going on with the entirety of the database layer (mySQL).

Comment: do you have the full stacktrace and not only those lines?

Comment: we would need to see the code of the model class

Answer (score 0):

Play enhances all Entity, models with a few things :

- Add an ID column,
- Adds getter/setters for public attributes,

It is probably one of those that is failing your application. When calling fullname are you sure it exists, that is is public and has no getter/setter method?